# Wix Not showing Repair Option in UI

Tags: wix

I implemented upgrade handlers and downgrade prevention

```
<Upgrade Id="$(var.UpgradeCode)">
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="no" Minimum="$(var.MinimumUpgradeVersion)" Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no" Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONINSTALLED" MigrateFeatures="yes" />
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMinimum="no" Property="NEWERVERSIONINSTALLED" />
</Upgrade>
```

And further on

```
<Custom Action="PreventDowngrading" After="FindRelatedProducts">NEWERVERSIONINSTALLED AND NOT Installed</Custom>
<RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize">PREVIOUSVERSIONINSTALLED</RemoveExistingProducts>
```

However, now when I try to double-click my MSI to do a repair the UI doesn't appear anymore. I am using the same Upgrade Code so Wix should automatically allow me to repair.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a major upgrade it might be better to use the majorupgrade element to make sure that you've included everything required. That's assuming you want a major upgrade, and I can't tell.

You are misunderstanding something. You (in WiX) use the majorupgrade element when you have a new version of your product that will replace the older one, and that includes a new ProductCode and the same UpgradeCode. This is nothing to do with repair. A repair is one of the options that can be available when you try to modify the existing installed product as defined by ProductCode, not UpgradeCode. A repair is not an upgrade or any kind of update. It repairs the existing product and will require the same MSI file that the product was originally installed from. The same UpgradeCode is nothing to do with repair.

Comment: Ah, yes I did mean to write ProductCode, not UpgradeCode.

Also, I investigated the <MajorUpgrade> element you mentioned and it turned out to be a much cleaner implementation than the one I had above. The side effect of doing so solved my repair issue.

Answer (score 0):

What GUI are you including? See an online tutorial here: http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface/ui-wizardry

Are you setting the [ARPNOREPAIR property](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/add-or-remove-programs-entries)? Check in the registry at the following location (subkey, check for DWORD NoRepair):

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

[image]